# Is it possible to toggle the "Disable all audio enhancements" option in the Windows Soundsettings through CMD / BATCH / VB?

Tags: windows, vb.net, batch-file, audio, registry

my problem:

I'm using the Freeware "Equalizer APO" to adjust the sound on my system.
When I'm using Windows normally I don't want it to be active. However when I'm starting a game (like CSGO) I want it to get active.

Background is that I'm using the EQ to turn down my bass so I can hear positional audio much better.

The thing is, the EQ writes changes into the registry as far as I understood and therefore doesn't need to be started for the effects to be active. Otherwise I would've just wrote me a macro that starts the EQ whenever I want.

So now my question is, is it possible to enable the "Disable all audio enhancements" function in the Properties of the Sound device via CMD / BATCH / VB? Because a possible solution I thought of was writing a script that can alter this setting through registry / batch or similar. Because enabling this option also removes the changes made by the EQ and therefore returns to no adjustment at all, which is what I want when not playing.

So whenever I would start a game I would press some keybind that executes the script to toggle the setting to off --> No / less bass enabled for gaming

Whenever I close my game again I would press another keybind that executes a script to toggle the setting to on --> All audio enhancements disabled -> No EQ -> normal audio without any changes for music, movies etc.

I know this is a very specific question but it really bugs me if it's possible or not. By my understanding every setting that can be made through the Windows GUI can somehow also be made through Batch / Registry, is that right?

Any other solution suggestions that would help me with my problem are also appreciated.